# Customize SliverAppBar title | Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

In 1st picture what I have,
In 2nd picture what I want,

I tried to use Positioned widget.
But, It didn't work.
and used padding it also did not work.

---

### [image: What I have]

[image: What I want]

There is my code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const ChatScreen({super.key});

@override
State createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverAppBar(
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: SafeArea(
                child: const CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(31, 27, 36, 1),
                  radius: 38,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                        'abc.com/286.png'),
                    radius: 35,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              background: Image.network(
                "abc.com/a.jpg", 
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(children: [
              Container(
                height: 250,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to stack the two widgets( Circle and Rectangle ) in the same sliver.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
return Scaffold(
   body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            pinned: true,
            expandedHeight: 200,
            flexibleSpace: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                    Positioned(
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: 25,
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: Image.network(
                            "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: SafeArea(
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(31, 27, 36, 1),
                              radius: 45,
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage: Image.asset('graphics/Contact.png').image,
                                radius: 42,
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        ),
        SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Column(children: [
            Container(
              height: 750,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ]),
        ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

And play with it to find out what you're searching for. Hope it helps :D